# Amazon EC2 vs Google App Engine

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, google-app-engine, phpmyadmin

For a Vaadin App, that uses a MySQL database and must have lots of files uploaded, which cloud platform is better? Amazon EC2 or Google App Engine? Can I use phpmyadmin in both?

Better in terms of:

1. Cost
2. Performance
3. Deployment and testing ease of management

Thanks!

Comment: Define "beter"? Performance? Cost ? Ease of management?

Comment: "Can I use phpmyadmin in both?" You shouldn't use it in **either**.

Comment: There is a key difference between EC2 and Google App Engine: EC2 is infrastructure as a service (IaaS) whereas GAE is platform as a service (PaaS); https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last time I checked, EC2 had way more features. EC2 is like being in a datacentre with all (mostly) the services you would want or expect.

If you don't need that, then it doesn't really matter.

Comment: It should be noted that Google does have an EC2 competitor (https://cloud.google.com/compute/)  though.